# Changing an entire column from YYYY-MM-DD to number of months in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

Suppose you have an entire column in MySQL that is YYYY-MM-DD, and you want to select it as the number of Months to a specific date, and also do it as a new column. Example date counting to can be March 2020.

So the following (**table_1**):

| Emp_Name | Hire_Date |
| --- | --- |
| Steve | 2018-03-28 |

To

| Emp_Name | Months_Employed |
| --- | --- |
| Steve | 24 |

But do this for every date in the Hire_Date column without manually entering the start and end date in DATEDIFF or TIMESTAMPDIFF.

I have the following, which returns a new column, but with NULL values:

```
select
Emp_Name, timestampdiff(month, 2021-04-01, Hire_Date) as Months_Employed
from
table_1
```

I have also tried DATEDIFF and dividing by 12 but it doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT for Answer that worked:

```
SELECT 
emp_name, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(month, hire_date, '2022-03-07')
AS months_employed
FROM table_1
```

Comment: Can you share the field type corresponding to 'Hire_Date'? @thesmiter1

Comment: Use the year part of each of your dates multiplied by 12 added to the month part of the same date to get number of months since year zero.  Not useful by itself, but then subtract those two to get elapsed months.  You can play with the days if you're concerned with partial and attained months, but that gets tricky comparing two last days of month, one with 30 days and the other with 31.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, startDate, endDate)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) is the correct function to use.

Date constants need to be shown as text strings.  `'2021-04-01'` is April Fools Day 2021. But `2021-04-01`, without the quotes, is an arithmetic expression evaluating to `2016`.

Here's a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x8ySGVNwCQ27zPDu8vwhkT/0).

```sql
SELECT emp_name, 
       hire_date, 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, hire_date, '2022-03-07') 
  FROM table_1
```

Comment: Hello! This worked, except with a minor change:
SELECT emp_name, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(month, hire_date, '2022-03-07')
AS months_employed
FROM table_1

Answer (score 0):

There is a mysql funtion that lets you achieve this by passing in the year and month.
***PERIOD_DIFF(P1,P2) - Returns the number of months between periods P1 and P2. P1 and P2 should be in the format YYMM or YYYYMM. Note that the period arguments P1 and P2 are not date values.***

```
SELECT PERIOD_DIFF(200802,200703);
    -> 11

SELECT emp_name,
   PERIOD_DIFF
   (
     202104,
     DATE_FORMAT(hire_date,"%Y%m")
   ) AS "Months_Employed"
FROM employees;
```

Comment: Some explanations are welcome, code only answers are generally less educating.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a generated column using the functionality like in this query:

```
select d,timestampdiff(month,'2020-03-01',d) X from dates where day(d)=1 and year(d)<=2020;
```

output:

| d | X |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | -2 |
| 2020-02-01 | -1 |
| 2020-03-01 | 0 |
| 2020-04-01 | 1 |
| 2020-05-01 | 2 |
| 2020-06-01 | 3 |
| ... | ... |

In your case something like:

```
alter table table_1 
modify column Months_Employed integer 
   generated always as (timestampdiff(month,'2020-03-01',Hire_Date)) stored;
```

More info: [ALTER TABLE and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html)